# Is it possible to export a tensorflow model with variable input size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, export, tensorflow.js

I am exporting a model using the [saved_model.Builder](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/Builder)

```
builder = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.Builder(output_dir)
inputs = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_x:0')
outputs = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output_y:0')

model_input = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(inputs)
model_output = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(outputs)

signature_definition = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={'inputs': model_input},
    outputs={'outputs': model_output},
    method_name= tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME)

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
   sess, [tf.saved_model.SERVING],
   signature_def_map={tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature_definition},
   clear_devices=True)

builder.save()
```

I can import and use this model in tensorflow.js. However, it only works for images that have the specific input size of the `input_x` tensor.
Is there a way to export the model in such a way that the input_x tensor can have a variable size?

- If the model is not exported and used in python, i.e., loading the weights and running inference on an image, the input image may have a different size than those used during training and the prediction will still work correctly.
- I'm guessing there are additional validations performed when the inference is done after the model has been exported. Why is this the case? Can they be removed?
- The easiest solution would be to resample/resize the new input images, but...

Comment: _The easiest solution would be to resample/resize the new input images, but..._ But what?

Comment: Why does it have to be the case? Why does the exported model fix the input size? It should work fine with images of any size.

Comment: Oh alright that’s what you meant. I misunderstood, sorry ;)

Comment: @Juan, even in Python, the model expect to have a fix inputShape. The model is not trained on a variable inputShape. As a result you cannot expect to have a model with dynamic inputShape in your model converted in js

Answer (score 0):

> If the model is not exported and used in python, i.e., loading the weights and running inference on an image, the input image may have a different size than those used during training and the prediction will still work correctly

If the model is not used at least for training in Python, why would it be written in Python? The advantage maybe would be for quantization that the converter provide out of the box. But it can be done as well by converting a js model to a js quantized model.

To answer the main question: a model always expect a certain inputShape. The inputShape can't be variable. This is true be it a model written in Python or in Js. Since the model itself cannot be written without fixing the inputShape, neither can the converter work without it.

> The easiest solution would be to resample/resize the new input images, but

It is the way to go. After training the model given a certain inputShape, the only thing applicable would be to resize or crop the images.

Answer (score 0):

This npm package can resample/resize to a given dimension and can be embedded in the js logic before running inference. 
[itk-image-pad-resample](https://www.npmjs.com/package/itk-image-pad-resample)